# Split a string of words by the first letter

Tags: r, regex, string

I am doing an entity resolution project and I need to split the author/coauthor names in a data set by the first letter.

For example, give the following two lines of data on authors named "A Gupta":

```
14_7 A Gupta; Luis Orozco-Barbosa ; Nicolas D Georganas<>Switching Modules for ATM Switching Systems and Their Interconnection Networks <>Computer Networks and ISDN Systems

15_30 Alok Gupta; B oris J ukic; Prabhudev Konana<>Pricing Virtual Private Networks - An Economic, Engineering and Experimental Approach,<>Business Modelling A MultiDisciplinary Approach Essays honor of Andrew B Whinston C Holsapple V Jacob H R Rao eds Kluwer Academic Publishers forthcoming
```

I want to generate a column named "author" with "A Gupta" and "Alok Gupta" in it, preferably all converted to "A Gupta".

The question is how to let the machine know "A Gupta" and "Alok Gupta" are the same "thing" in this problem.

I have tried to learn the regular expression for it, but I don't know how to search for a word that begins with a letter (A) and also take the next word that begins with another letter (G) and take them out of the string.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not exhaustive, but `sub('.*?([A-Z]).*?( .+?) ?;.*', '\\1\\2', x)`, where `x` is a vector of the lines in question.

Comment: @alistaire Thank you for the help. I typed it into regex101.com, but I still don't understand what the symbols mean. Is there a way to find a verbal explanation to the symbols? Thanks.

Comment: `.` is any character; `*?` specifies the previous token is repeated 0 or more times, but as few as possible; `(...)` is a capturing group; `[A-Z]` is any capital letter. So far, it captures the first capital, but not what's after it. A second capturing group captures a space followed by anything `.`, repeated 1 or more times, but as few as possible `+?`. After the capturing group there may or may not be one space ` ?`, but definitely a `;`. `.*` captures the rest of the line. The replacement `\\1\\2` reassembles the two captured groups: the first initial and the space and last name.

Comment: I have a question regarding the word "token". If `.` is any character, and `*?` specifies the previous token is repeated 0 or more times, but as few as possible, what is the "token" referring to? Is it the `.`? If so, taking the first line of data as an example, the first character is `1`, what is done to it? Thanks.

Comment: A "token" is just an element of the regex, in that case `.`. Here, `.*?` will select everything from the start to the first capital letter. Note there's a difference between what's _selected_ (what `sub` replaces; the whole line here) and what's _captured_ (the two parts in parentheses, which get substituted back in by `\\1\\2`). Also, you could actually omit some of the lazy quantifiers and use normal greedy ones: `'.*([A-Z]).*( .+?) ?;.*'`.

Comment: Let's see if I can translate the first half of regex you wrote: `.*?([A-Z])`. `.` selects any and all characters in the string. `.*?` selects every character along with null characters. `.*?([A-Z])` captures all capital letters from the selected. Is this correct? Moreover, how should I interpret the second half, `.*?(.+?)?;.*`, and what is the relationship with the first half? Does the second half start from the beginning and ignores what is captured by the first half? Is it correct in referring them as halves?  Lastly, what is meant by "repeated 0 or more times"? Thanks you for the explanatio

Comment: Given a list of names:  `A Gupta; Luis Orozco-Barbosa ; Nicolas D Georganas` or `Alok Gupta; B oris J ukic; Prabhudev Konana` is there a way to select from that "A Gupta" and "Alok Gupta"? I was able to separate the names from the rest of the string, but this somehow is still giving me headache. My strategy is to find "Gupta" then take the previous word with it. But I have yet to find a way to do that.

Comment: Sure, that's much simpler: `sub('([^;]+);.*', '\\1', x)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how should I modify the code if "A Gupta" does not appear as the first author? The code seems to find only the first segment of string before the semi-colon?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you know about the data. If you're looking for a specific name, you can just use something like `sub('.*(A[^;]*?Gupta).*', '\\1', x)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to parse the names. Thanks! Now, is there a way to select everything besides what is selected by your expression? I tried `AKumar$Coauthor = sub('.*(A[^;]*?Gupta).*', "", AKumar$Coauthor)`, but it gave me blank..

Comment: `sub('A[^;]*?Gupta', '', x)`

Comment: I will try to learn the two lines very well. Thank you for the help!